# Failed in clear markers in Google Map API3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have created a function to add the marker when there is no marker on map or remove the original marker and added a new one to replace it. However, i can add the first part of script successfully to add the marker on map. however, the original marker can not be removed and new marker could not added when i click the map again. Can anyone suggest what is the problem?

```
/*Create a listener to record the Click event of the google map and define it as the starting point (i.e. Origin in Google Direction
service*/
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  if (origin == null) {
    origin = event.latLng;

    lat = origin.lat();
    lng = origin.lng();
    UpdateLatLng();  

    var startimage = 'images/Start4.png';
    StartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: origin,
         icon: startimage
     });
  } else {
 //Relocate the Starting point and assign the new position to Textbox
    alert ("The starting point was relocated on screen"); 
    StartMarker.setMap(null);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);
    directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
    var origin = event.latLng;  
    lat = origin.lat();
    lng = origin.lng();
    UpdateLatLng(); 
    var startimage = 'images/Start4.png';
    StartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: origin,
         icon: startimage
     });
    } 
});
```

Comment: Why don't you try to replace the Original marker like?:
StartMarker.setPosition(newLatLongPostion);
StartMarker.setIcon(newIcon);

Comment: I have removed the 'StartMarker.setMap(null)' and     StartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: origin,
         icon: startimage
     });
and add a new code "  StartMarker.setPosition(origin.getposition());"...
however, only a new marker is added but the original marker and the route remains existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var StartMarker = null;
/*Create a listener to record the Click event of the google map and define it as the starting point (i.e. Origin in Google Direction
service*/
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  if (!StartMarker) {
    origin = event.latLng;
    lat = origin.lat();
    lng = origin.lng();

    StartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: origin
     });
  } else {
 //Relocate the Starting point and assign the new position to Textbox
    alert ("The starting point was relocated on screen"); 
    StartMarker.setMap(null);
    var origin = event.latLng;  
    lat = origin.lat();
    lng = origin.lng();
    StartMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: origin
     });
    } 
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_click2addMarker.html)

Comment: Thanks... your example solve most of my syntax error...
It worked well in case i remove the following code
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);
    directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
Since the route may be Null or vice versa during the click event...
how can i remove the route if it is existed???

Comment: That is a different question.  You haven't included enough code in your question to answer that (which is why I removed those lines).  You probably have a scope problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the existing `Marker` like:

```
// Will change the poisition
StartMarker.setPosition(origin); 
// Will change the Icon
StartMarker.setIcon(startimage);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice...
However, the problem remains unsolved...
the old markers could not be removed as expected...


else {
  alert ("The starting point was relocated on screen"); //Relocate the Starting point and assign the new position to Textbox
  //StartMarker.setMap(null);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);
  directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
        var origin = event.latLng; 
  lat = origin.lat();
  lng = origin.lng();
  UpdateLatLng(); 
  StartMarker.setPosition(origin);

Comment: Can you create an example at: jsfiddle.net